# How to go back to a commit for a fix/patch, but not alter anything after?

Tags: git

I want to go back to a version of a code that is old and make a fix for only that version. I don't want the fix to be integrated into master, because any versions that come after the one that needs a fix, don't suffer from the problem. Taking as an example, the diagram below, I would like to move to **C3**, make a fix, commit the changes, but **not** merge those changes on any of the commits that are below it (**C4** and **C5**).

I was thinking of doing

1. `git checkout C3`
2. `git checkout -b patch`
3. Apply the fix
4. `git commit -m "Fix for an old version of the software"`
5. `git checkout C3`
6. `git merge patch`

And leave it there for later compilation of the software. Not apply the fix to C4 or C5 because they don't suffer from the problem. That's what I would do, but I am not sure if that is correct. Hence the question: Is there a way to go back to a commit for a fix/patch, but not alter anything after the fix or patch is done? Or in other words, not merge changes into anything after the commit of interest? Any changes I make to **C3** to fix that version of the software I want them to stay there and then **HEAD** and **master** still point to **C5** after C3 is compiled and released with a fix such that others can continue to work on **C5** as if nothing ever happened.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is physically impossible to alter *any* commit.  So what you are proposing here is easy and just trivially works: commit `C3` remains commit `C3` forever.  You will, however, need to release a patched version of `version 1.0.4`, because that's commit `C3`, which is unchanged.

You cannot merge your bug fix commit into commit `C3`, but there is no need to do that.  It is *a branch*.  You've drawn your commits with newer ones towards the bottom; I like to draw mine with newer commits towards the right.  So I would draw your situation like this:

```
     tag:v1.0.4
         |
         v
C1--C2--C3
          \
           C4 <-- tag:v1.0.5
             \
              C5   <-- master (HEAD)
               ^
               |
           tag:v1.0.6
```

When you go back to `C3` and attach a branch name there (and make it `HEAD`), you get:

```
     tag:v1.0.4
         |
         v
C1--C2--C3   <-- patch (HEAD)
          \
           C4 <-- tag:v1.0.5
             \
              C5   <-- master
               ^
               |
           tag:v1.0.6
```

When you make a new commit, the new commit's parent is `C3` and the name `patch` points to the new commit:

```
     tag:v1.0.4
         |
         v
C1--C2--C3--C7   <-- patch (HEAD)
          \
           C4 <-- tag:v1.0.5
             \
              C5   <-- master
               ^
               |
           tag:v1.0.6
```

If all is good with commit `C7` (I skipped C6 here by mistake, but might as well leave it—every commit has a unique but big and ugly hash ID anyway so these just stand in for real commit hash IDs), you can tag it as `v1.0.4.1` or whatever tag you would use to let people upgrade from version 1.0.4 without going all the way to 1.0.5.  (Perhaps you should have left some room between 1.0.4 and 1.0.5. :-) )

If no patch is required for version 1.0.5 or 1.0.6, there is nothing left to do.

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained. I understand now.